# Are specific natural attacks always primary or secondary or do they depend on the monster?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, attack, wild-shape, natural-weapon

I am working on my character sheet for a druid, and on all my attacks for a wild shape form. When I looked at the list under [universal monster rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks) each of the attacks is listed as primary or secondary. I was under the impression that for each creature it would change if the attack was primary or secondary, not that the attacks themselves would always be one or the other.

Is this true or are the animal form specific rules and this chart lists the general rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules under the universal monster rules are the general rules. Exceptions do exist, though I'm not sure if any exist for animals.

In fact, this is even mentioned in d20pfsrd, just under the table:

> Some creatures treat one or more of their attacks differently, such as Dragons, which always receive 1-1/2 times their Strength bonus on damage rolls with their bite attack. These exceptions are noted in the creature’s description.

I am not aware of any master table of exceptions to the usual classifications of monster/animal natural attacks (though one might exist for wild shape or animal companions or other such player-centered material).

Comment: Since I am unable to find even a proper table, chart, or calculator for the forms and changes a druid can get for wild shape, Im going to assume there is no master table of exceptions. I have found outdated or incomplete items however. If I am wrong I hope someone points me towards any of those resources.

Comment: @Fering there wouldn't be, as it would have to be updated every time they released a new beastiary, AP, or Campaign setting and it had a creature with an exception.  All you need to do is look at the stat block of the animal you would be wild shaping into and see if they get full bab on their attacks.

Answer (score 2):

This list indicates the general case. Unless it is specified in the monster's description, a bite is a primary attack and a tail slap is a secondary attack.

As an example of such exception, see the [giraffe](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/herd-animals/herd-animal-giraffe/):

> A giraffe’s hoof attacks are primary attacks and its slam attack is a secondary attack.